# Ipv6 - Connect : Network is unreachable

Tags: vmware, ipv6

I've just created a virtual Ubuntu machine in VMWare Player but ipv6 is not working.

When I try to ping Google with

```
ping6 www.google.be
```

I get

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

When I use Wireshark, I see that I'm not sending any Icmpv6 packet.

How can I fix it ? Does anyone have an idea ?

---

**EDIT:**

I can ping my router with ipv6. Thus, I can send Icmpv6 packets.

Is the problem related to ipv6 autoconfiguration ?

Comment: What is the output of the command: `lsmod | grep -qw ipv6 && echo "IPv6 kernel driver loaded and configured." || echo "IPv6 not configured and/or driver loaded on the system."`

Comment: It is : `IPv6 not configured and/or driver loaded on the system.`

Comment: Did you configure a v6 address for the computer and did you confirm that the v6 route is added?  Did you also confirm that this is in Bridged mode (and not NAT mode) for the guest network adapter?  (It's probable auto negotiation is failing or routing is failing and needs a lot more configuration to make work)

Comment: I have no problem when the guest network adapter is in Bridged mode but ipv6 doesn't work in NAT mode. My VM hasn't any default ipv6 route. Do I have to enter it manually? Cannot ipv6 do it by itself with SLAAC?

Answer (score 7):

#### How to know if IPv6 is configured and working on ubuntu?

Run the command:

```
[ -f /proc/net/if_inet6 ] && echo 'IPv6 OK' || echo 'No IPv6'
```

If the output is

```
IPv6 OK
```

Then your system can work with IPV6.

Now run the command:

```
lsmod | grep -qw ipv6 && echo "IPv6 kernel driver loaded and configured." || echo "IPv6 not configured and/or driver loaded on the system."
```

If the output is:

```
IPv6 kernel driver loaded and configured.
```

This means the IPV6 is configured and you can use it but if(and this is your case from comment above) the answer is

```
IPv6 not configured and/or driver loaded on the system.
```

this means IPV6 is not configured in your system, and for that you can't use IPV6 yet.

#### How to enable IPV6 in Ubuntu

Run this command:

```
sudo modprobe ipv6
```

Now test if this works:

```
lsmod | grep ipv6
```

The outpu should be like :

```
ipv6                  XXXX xX
```

source and more information :http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/systemcheck-kernel.html

Comment: The output is `IPv6 OK`.
Ipv6 worked on an other virtual machine with the same os.

Comment: complete the next check, your system is not configured to use IPV6 yet

Comment: Running `modprobe ipv6` does not modify the output of `lsmod | grep ipv6`.

Comment: you have to do that with root, `sudo modprobe ipv6`

Comment: That does not change anything.

Comment: take a look on the link

Comment: @user426862 Did you figure it out? `sudo modprobe ipv6` does not change my lsmod output either, even though it is supported by the kernel.

Comment: link no longer working. I have a user with this same issue

Comment: `modinfo ipv6` says `modinfo: ERROR: Module ipv6 not found.` on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: The correct link for that source is https://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/docs/HOWTO/other-formats/html_single/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO.html#SYSTEMCHECK-KERNEL (found it by searching on the not found page that comes up on the original link), but it doesn't offer any more insight. `sudo modprobe ipv6` does nothing for me as well

Answer (score 1):

Today I also encounter this issue. From the answer of Maxthux.

`[ -f /proc/net/if_inet6 ] && echo 'IPv6 OK' || echo 'No IPv6'` returns ok

```
lsmod | grep -qw ipv6 && echo "IPv6 kernel driver loaded and configured." || echo "IPv6 not configured and/or driver loaded on the system." returns IPv6 not configured and/or driver loaded on the system.
```

And `sudo modprobe ipv6` has no influence on `lsmod | grep ipv6` 's empty output.

After about a whole afternoon's searching, I find a way out.

Here is the detail setup for my ipv6.

I use vps of digitalocean, and I've use only ipv4 for about a year. Recently for ios app, I've to setup ipv6 of my vps. I refer to this post, and it's a little too old, so there have some changes.

**A**: login the degitalocean droplets manage page, click the enable link of ipv6 on the droplet page. Here it may ask you to shutdown you droplet before you enable it. After enabled, on the networking page you can see the below pic. Here I mask the ip information.

[image]

**B**: Temporarily add ipv6 address.
Login to the system with ssh, use this command:

```
ip -6 addr add new_IPv6_address_in_range/64 dev eth0
```

and check it with `ip -6 addr show eth0`

Here you can `host -t AAAA google.com`

```
root@xx:~# host -t AAAA google.com
google.com has IPv6 address 2404:6800:4003:c00::71
```

but `ping6 2404:6800:4003:c00::71` will result

> Connect: Network is unreachable

**C**: Add additional ipv6 address

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

add below to this file, then change address and gateway according to you droplet page.

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
        address primary_ipv6_address
        netmask 64
        gateway ipv6_gateway
        autoconf 0
        dns-nameservers 2001:4860:4860::8844 2001:4860:4860::8888 209.244.0.3
```

Then reboot you system:

After reboot, check it.

```
root@xx:~# host -t AAAA google.com
google.com has IPv6 address 2404:6800:4003:c00::66
root@xx:~# ping6 -c4  2404:6800:4003:c00::66
PING 2404:6800:4003:c00::66(2404:6800:4003:c00::66) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2404:6800:4003:c00::66: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=2.08 ms
64 bytes from 2404:6800:4003:c00::66: icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=2.01 ms
64 bytes from 2404:6800:4003:c00::66: icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=1.83 ms
64 bytes from 2404:6800:4003:c00::66: icmp_seq=4 ttl=51 time=1.81 ms

--- 2404:6800:4003:c00::66 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.815/1.937/2.085/0.118 ms
```