# IPv6 does not work on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, ipv6

I'm trying to get IPv6 working on Ubuntu 14.04 but failed. IPv4 however works fine, while both work well on Win 10.

It can just obtain IPv6 address but when tested on https://ipv6-test.com, It failed like:

[image]

When running the command `ip -6 addr`, I got:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::6af7:28ff:fe26:5aec/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1492 state UNKNOWN qlen 3
    inet6 2001:250:1001:2500:fc08:5666:3adb:923/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 258228sec preferred_lft 82394sec
    inet6 2001:250:1001:2500:d82d:cb77:2a26:f019/64 scope global dynamic 
       valid_lft 258228sec preferred_lft 171828sec
    inet6 fe80::d82d:cb77:2a26:f019/10 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I have tried the method proposed on [Ipv6 - Connect : Network is unreachable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645008/ipv6-connect-network-is-unreachable/645014#645014) . But fail to run `sudo modprobe ipv6`.

For `ip -6 route`, the result looks like:

```
2001:250:1001:2500::/64 dev ppp0  proto kernel  metric 256  expires 258403sec mtu 1491
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev wlan0  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/10 dev ppp0  metric 1  mtu 1491
fe80::/10 dev ppp0  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1491
default via fe80::cecc:81ff:fec0:d75d dev ppp0  proto ra  metric 1024  expires 1003sec mtu 1491
```

Connected by DSL, I have no idea whether to fix `eth0` or `ppp0`. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/890560/edit) your question and the output of `hostname -I`.  If you are using a router, try connecting your Ubuntu computer directly to the DSL modem and see if you get different results.

Comment: Please post the output of `ip -6 route`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton , posted the output but still have no idea with it.

Comment: @user68186, the result seems like `192.168.150.1 115.154.53.211 2001:250:1001:2500:fc08:5666:3adb:923 2001:250:1001:2500:d82d:cb77:2a26:f019`. I have a port to connect the campus network without a router, but I have to add a DSL connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works for me. I 'm going to post my solution in case someone encounters the same problem.

```
ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1492 state UNKNOWN qlen 3
    inet6 2001:250:1001:2500:fc08:5666:3adb:923/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 258228sec preferred_lft 82394sec
    inet6 2001:250:1001:2500:d82d:cb77:2a26:f019/64 scope global dynamic 
       valid_lft 258228sec preferred_lft 171828sec
    inet6 fe80::d82d:cb77:2a26:f019/10 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Two Global IPv6 address are allocated but only the global one is needed by checking the router. Hence we just delete the address.

Edit `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-privacy.conf` at the last line:

`net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 2`

to `net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 0`

Then restart the network.

```
sudo sysctl --system
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Done!