# IPv6 not working from terminal

Tags: ssh, ipv6, vps, scp

I was able to scp files from my VPS using IPv6 but after some mess-ups (like using shadowsocks and Foxyproxy to circumvent [GFW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall)) with my Ubuntu 16.04 I have a strange problem. I can access IPv6 websites (like ipv6.google.com) from my firefox browser, but `ping6 ipv6.google.com` returns nothing (sometimes `Network is unreachable` sometimes 100% packet loss). And I can't ssh or scp from my VPS using IPv6 anymore.

I have read questions like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645008/ipv6-connect-network-is-unreachable) but the solution is not working for me. As in that question, running `[ -f /proc/net/if_inet6 ] && echo 'IPv6 OK' || echo 'No IPv6'` gives `IPv6 OK`. So this means my system is able to make an IPv6 connection.

I think it has something to do with proxies but I'm not sure what to look at. Could anyone suggest some solutions?

`ifconfig` gives:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:4d:7b:b8:4f:7d  
      inet addr:166.111.66.250  Bcast:166.111.67.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::10d8:ad64:c0dc:f66a/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:7817729 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:99607 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:656752046 (656.7 MB)  TX bytes:51522303 (51.5 MB)
      Interrupt:16 Memory:df200000-df220000 

is0       Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4  
      inet6 addr: fe80::200:5efe:a66f:42fa/64 Scope:Link
      UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1280  Metric:1
      RX packets:106 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:69 errors:35 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:9904 (9.9 KB)  TX bytes:3408 (3.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:89984 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:89984 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:57274557 (57.2 MB)  TX bytes:57274557 (57.2 MB)

wlx30b49e2f621f Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:b4:9e:2f:62:1f  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: Your server may have IPv6 _installed_ but it doesn't have any global IPv6 addresses configured.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The problem occurred on my  local computer, not the server.

Comment: Then why are you mentioning your VPS? I am confused by your comment.